# KextManagerLoadKextWithIdentifier fail to load kext.

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, xnu

I'm trying to load my kext with the user-space method `KextManagerLoadKextWithIdentifier` which failed for the following reasons.

```
default 06:45:47.223261 -0700   kernel  CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1030b8000):
       p=827[client] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
default 06:45:47.230176 -0700   kextd   Error: Kext 
       com.my.dd-driver - not found/unable to create.
```

My driver is indeed unsigned but I've set boot-args with `kext-dev-mode=1` to accept unsigned drivers.

If I try to load the driver from terminal using `kextload` it's working.

Any idea why `KextManagerLoadKextWithIdentifier` is not working ?

Comment: Is your kext installed in `/Library/Extensions`? Can you post your kext's info.plist file? Given that you mention `kext-dev-mode`, I assume you're on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite?) Is your process running as root (sudo)?

Comment: Actually, I'm working on Sierra, and I can still load the driver using kextload without signing it. is `kext-dev-mode` obsolete ?

Comment: `kext-dev-mode` is obsolete, it only worked in 10.10. I assume you must have SIP (system integrity protection) disabled then, as that's required for loading unsigned kexts from 10.11 onwards.